# Do AppBundle apps rank higher than APK in Google Play?

Tags: google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

Does Google Play promote AppBundles by giving such apps higher search rankings? Have you noticed an increase in your app's popularity after migrating from APK to AppBundle? I remember seeing similar statements from Google when App Bundles were announced, but I can't find them now. If you have experience with both APKs and AppBundles, please share your insights on the matter.